# In Rails, how do I write a finder method ordering by a column I don't want to return?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-order-by, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord

With Rails 5, how do you write a finder that orders by a column that you don't necessarily want to return?  I have

```
Person.select("id, name").order('votes DESC').limit(15)
```

meaning I only want to return the "id" and "name" attributes of the model, but I would like the model itself ordered by the "votes" column.  However, running the above gives the error

```
ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError: missing attribute: votes
```

How do I write a finder that orders by a column I don't always want to return?

Comment: Are you sure field votes exists?

Comment: Yes.  When I include "votes" in the field list everything works fine.

Comment: What you have should work fine (I even checked a similar query with 5.1). Do you have a default scope or something in `Person`? What does `Person.select("id, name").order('votes DESC').limit(15).to_sql` have to say?

Answer (score 1):

1. [pluck](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck) should do the trick but it returns an array of [id, name].

   `Person.order('votes DESC').limit(15).pluck(:id, :name)`
2. [find_by_sql](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/find_by_sql/class) returns an array of ActiveRecord objects

   `Person.find_by_sql('SELECT id, name FROM persons ORDER BY votes DESC LIMIT 15')`

Comment: Please note that `pluck` will return a nested array where your original example using `select` would have returned `ActiveRecord` objects.

Comment: I would like to return ACtiveRecord objects.  Did you include the native SQL solution because there is no way in traiditional Rails to do what I'm asking?

Comment: Updated the answer with find_by_sql.

Answer (score 0):

```
Person.select("id", "name").order("votes DESC").limit(15)
```

Should do the trick. Just need to separate the attributes to be selected.